# RemoteApp hosted on VirtualBox Windows Server 2008 from Windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualbox, remoteapp, windows-10

I need to test a few things related to remote apps on Windows Server 2008 R2. The host system is Windows 10 and I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 in VirtualBox.

1. Of course, I enabled the server for Remote Display (port 3389) in VirtualBox settings and I also allowed connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop in the system properties of the guest. Now, I can access the desktop from Windows 10, using the IPv4 address and the port 3389.
2. I installed Remote Desktop Services and added a new application into the RemoteApp Manager. I created the .rdp file and copied it to the Windows 10 host system.
3. Now, when I try to run it, I get an error about the remote computer not being found. I can see that`full address` is `WIN-U28S71NJR4K` inside the file. If I change it to the IP I use for Remote Desktop Connection, then  I get a login dialog with my Windows 10 account and an option for using another account. If I insert the password for my Windows 10 account it says that the remote computer does not support RemoteApp.
4. When I run it from the server, the RDP file initiates the applications correctly

So, I don't know what am I missing. Is it possible to access remote applications hosted on VirtualBox Windows Server 2008 R2 from Windows 10?

Comment: The tcpip stack of the win10 will limit you. Its for a lab? as if for a business I would not do that at all.

Comment: Yes, it is just for testing something, not for business. Can I reset the stack?